# How to configure a Spring Boot Application that uses tomcat and has a dependency to another Application uses tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I have a Spring Boot application (App1) that uses an embedded Tomcat. To specify the Port I added `server.port=8080` to the application.properties in my main application
and it works fine.

Now I add a dependency to another Spring Boot application (App2) in the pom.xml (because in App1 I need access to the Beans from App2). App2 uses also an embedded Tomcat on a different port.

But when I run App1 it crashes because App2 want to also use the same `server.port` and configurations - that obviously cannot work.

Is this even possible what I want to achieve? And how would I do this that I can run both App2 in App1? If this is not possible, is it possible to access the Beans from App2 in App1?

Comment: If all you need are beans from another app, you should create a shared library (jar), and use it in both the apps.

Comment: That's a typical case for a multi-modul project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two options, depending on which one suits your use case conceptually:

- you have two Spring Boot applications that need to **share the same code**: extract this code to a separate project (a regular Java library), build it as a jar file and include into both projects as a dependency; an example could be found in the [Creating a Multi Module Project](https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/) guide;
- you have two Spring Boot applications, one of them needs to access the **functionality** of another: provide and access this functionality as an API, instead of directly importing the beans. There are multiple ways to do this. For example, you could expose the bean functionality as a REST API using Spring's [@RestController](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html), and access them from the other side using [RestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html). See the following guides: [Building a RESTful Web Service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/), [Consuming a RESTful Web Service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/)